# How to split column values when list index goes out of range in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently learning python and trying few pandas functions in Jupyter notebook. I'm trying to split the column values based on '/' delimiter using lambda function and the error 'list index out of range' threw. The column looks as below

```
column_name
---------------
screen1/screen2
screen2
screen3/screen4
```

Now, I've used the lambda functions as below:

```
df['new_column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(lambda x:x.split('/')[1])

df.head()
```

Can someone pls help me out how can I overcome the 'list index out of range' error and split these values into a new column ?

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: when you have 0 `/`, you get a list with 1 item and the error

Answer (score 1):

The output you expect is unclear, however you can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the strings, and the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor to slice the data without worrying about IndexError.

Depending on whether you want the second or last element, you could do:

```
df['second'] = df['col'].str.split('/').str[1]
```

or

```
df['last']= df['col'].str.split('/').str[-1]
```

output:

```
               col   second     last
0  screen1/screen2  screen2  screen2
1          screen2      NaN  screen2
2  screen3/screen4  screen4  screen4
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I am wondering why the lambda function didn't work well

Comment: Because, using `apply`, you evaluate each element individually. When there is no `/` you perform `['string'][1]`, which is impossible as there is only a single element in the list. Using the `str` accessor automatically handles this case and outputs NaN if no slicing is possible.